# WPF list view's grid view area mouse capture

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to check whether the double click happens inside the WPF ListView's GridView area ? If we are using listview mouse double click event, the double click on the scrollbar of the listview also triggers mouse double click event.

I am looking for a way to identify the mouse double click is only on top of the list view items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.horizontalscrollbarheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.verticalscrollbarwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties to help you with this. Here is the example that detects whether the vertical `ScrollBar` is being used:

```
double mouseXPositionInListView = Mouse.GetPosition(yourListView).X;
if (mouseXPositionInListView > yourListView.ActualWidth - 
    SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth - yourListView.Padding.Right) 
{
    // The user is scrolling vertically
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

If you want to ignore clicks on the `GridView` column header area, then just adjust the above code to include the `Height` of the header. You can get the `Height` of the header using the `GridViewColumnHeader.Height` property. Note that this is not a `static` property like the previous one, so you'll have to get that from your `GridView`.

Comment: Thanks. But where this code used ? in mouse double click event or ??

Comment: yes. it is working. But this is only for scrollbar. But how abt clicking on the column header ? if we double click on header, it will trigger mouse double click.